# Start video on after spesific page location triggered on scroll event -JavaScript(react-web)

Tags: javascript, video

I want the video to start when I get to the position where the video is while scrolling down

Here is my code example:

Script:

```
const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      setCurrentPosition(window.pageYOffset)
    })
  }, [])
```

and HTML

```
<div className={styles.image__wrapper}>
     <img  src={VideoAsset} alt="video" />
       <Fragment>
          {currentPosition > 2450 && (
            <video autoplay controls src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
          )}
       </Fragment>
</div>
```

the page position is dynamically calculated at 'currentPosition' and the video is null when the scroll position points there. But we are not sure that this is a healthy structure. Anyone have a different suggestion?

Thanks for your time

SOLVED -- HERE IS SOLUTION

```
  const videoPlayRect = () => {
    const video = document.querySelector('video')
    const videoRect = video.getBoundingClientRect()

    if (
      videoRect.top >= 0 &&
      videoRect.left >= 0 &&
      videoRect.bottom <=
        (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      videoRect.right <=
        (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    ) {
      video.play()
    } else {
      video.pause()
    }
  }
```

and HTML

```
<Fragment>
  <video
   onScroll={videoPlayRect}
   className={styles.video__content}
   autoPlay
   muted
   loop
   controls
   src={Video}
/>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with React specifically, but using getBoundingClientRect method on the video element and comparing its position to the scroll position is a perfectly fine solution.  Another one you could look into would be the intersection observer api.  This would be more heavily recommended if you have numerous elements relying on scroll position / intersect.  Either solution is fine in this simple case.

Comment: Actually, the point shot you said solved what I wanted. thanks for your precious time, you saved me from a crisis! @Zbow